# Need help with character creation and clothing

Tags: modeling, animation, sculpting

I started learning Blender a few months ago, just as a hobby, and want to make a few animation videos. I don't worry about quality as I just want to create videos.

So far I am using addons (like building generator, urbaniq) to create scenes as I don't need to worry about render quality so a few issues here and there are ok. So far ready-made models are working well for me. But the only issue is with the characters.

Now I am starting into character animation and that's where I am confused. I require low poly characters for stories but all they need to look different and with different dresses. so I need

1. Multiple characters (males, females, children)
2. Different dresses
3. Different poses
4. Different animation

Now I am not sure if should I start from scratch in Blender and do everything there or if I can use a combination of other software like DAZ etc. Again I just want to create animated stories and not worry about quality just the bare minimum to get stuff done.

Comment: Too many questions at once.

Comment: DAZ like [Daz 3D](https://www.daz3d.com/)? I would not call these models low-poly. If you don't mind a low-poly style check out Imphenzia's tutorials (https://youtu.be/PTWV67qUX2k or this older one: https://youtu.be/1jHUY3qoBu8). Or Grant Abbitt here: https://youtu.be/iMar3keWaUo and [Joey Carlino's tips](https://youtu.be/GAIZkIfXXjQ). With some practice, you can model such characters quickly. Low-poly characters also have the advantage that you can model the environment in a low-poly style and it looks uniform and nice, and it's done quickly.